# Webflux, Reactive Publisher based flow got interrupted in the middle

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

This method suppose to fetch object from MongoDB and based on them call external API twice per object and then save outcome back to DB.

Not sure why entire flow got interrupted in **5th line**.(been debugging marked function got called as last). I've tried to make sure all called functions are reactive. At this point have no idea what's wrong. Also quite new with reactive programming.

```
    fun fillMissingThings() {
        reactiveThingsRepository.findAllBySomeCondition(EMPTY)
                .map { it.name.getName() }
                .flatMap(this::fetchIdByName) <-- this method is called last
                .flatMap(this::fetchThingById)
                .flatMap { reactiveThingsRepository.save(it) }
                .subscribe()
    }

    fun fetchIdByName(name: String): Flux<String> =
            webClient.get()
                    .uri(someUrlBasedOnName)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(Array<SearchIdDto>::class.java)
                    .onErrorResume { Flux.empty() }
                    .retry(3)
                    .flatMap { Flux.fromArray(it) }
                    .map { it.id!! }

    fun fetchThingById(thingId: String): Flux<Thing> =
            webClient.get()
                    .uri(someUrlBasedOnId)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(ThingDto::class.java)
                    .onErrorResume { Flux.empty() }
                    .retry(3)
                    .map { it.toEntity().setDefaultValues() }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted"? The process end, but no error and doesn't get saved to db?

Comment: Exactly that. See logs that the first request via webclient is called and I got 200 back. But  no 2nd request sent neither anything is saved to db